# How to use result of \FPeval computation "inline"?

Tags: fp

Instead of writing something as, which works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}    
\begin{document}

\FPeval{\result}{4*0.3} %store the result in `\result` first then:

\begin{tabular}[c]{| m{\result in}  | m{\result in} | }\hline
a&b\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to do the multiplication shown above, right inside the `tabular` environment. i.e. "inline"

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I do not know what the syntax is. It seems with `\FPeval` one has to do the computation first, store it in some register (called `\result` in the above), then later use the computed value by referencing that register again.

But I want to just to do something like `\FPeval{4*0.3}` and have the result be there directly. As in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{| m{\FPeval{}{4*0.3} in}  | m{\FPeval{}{4*0.3} in} | }\hline
a&b\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which does not work. Gives syntax errors, This also does not work for some reason

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{| m{\FPeval{\result}{4*0.3}\result in}  | m{\FPeval{\result}{4*0.3}\result in} | }\hline
a&b\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to just do the multiplication "inline" directly, without having to introduce new register variables?

TL 2019

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use xfp instead of fp:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{| m{\fpeval{4*0.3} in}  | m{\fpeval{4*0.3} in} | }\hline
a&b\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```